# Node JS - Pusher trigger not working

Tags: node.js, triggers, pusher

The trigger function is not working for me in Node JS.

I can not see anything in the debug console that Pusher is receiving data.

```
var Pusher = require('pusher');
var pusher = new Pusher({
    appId: 'test',
    key: 'test',
    secret: 'test',
    cluster: 'mt1',
    encrypted: true
});

pusher.trigger(userId, 'Admin-Email', {
     message: 'test'
});
```

Comment: The `appId`, `key`, and `secret` need to be set to the values which are displayed in the Pusher dashboard.

Comment: @WillSewell I know should set appId,key and secret.
I just didn't showed here

Comment: I can't see anything that is obviously wrong then. Does the call to `pusher.trigger` return anything that might indicate the source of an error? Or does it log anything? If not it might be best to contact [the Pusher support team](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us) so that they can check your app ID/key/secret.

Comment: Interestingly, I started to play with Pusher/node.js and Angular 7 today, and none, mean literally none!, of the examples on pusher.channels page worked. I started to reduce the code and slimmed it down to a basic piece of code as above - still no go. Removing or setting encrypted/forceTLS to false did not help.